# Stuck with a mocha test on a mongoose express app

Tags: unit-testing, express, mongoose, mocha.js

Here's the deal, I have this Foo model in /models/foo.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var Foo = new Schema({
  Bar : {type: Boolean, default: false},
  Baz   : String
});

Foo.statics.isBar = function(id, callback) {
  return this.update({'_id': id}, {$set: {Bar: true}}, callback);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Foo', Foo);
```

Now I am trying to write a test with mocha (with chai expect library) in /test/modelFoo.js.

```
var chai     = require('chai'),
    expect   = chai.expect,
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Foo      = require('../models/foo');

// ...connecting to the db and creating a test Foo...

describe('Foo Bar', function(){
  it('should set Bar to true', function(done){
    Foo.findOne({}, function(err, foo) {
      Foo.isBar(foo._id, function() {
        expect(foo.Bar).to.be.true;
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The assertion fails. Looking in mongo, Bar is still false.

What's giving me a headache is that elsewhere I have this route

```
app.get('/bar/:id', function(req, res){
  Foo.isBar(req.params.id, function(err) {
    if(err) // handle it
    else res.redirect('back');
  });
});
```

... and it nicely sets Bar to true.

I don't get what's wrong. Is it my test? my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `update` won't update your model instance (it will update the database, though, that's why your route works okay).

So you're going to have to retrieve it from the database again before you can check it:

```
  Foo.isBar(foo._id, function() {
    Foo.findOne(foo._id, function(err, updatedFoo) {
      expect(updatedFoo.Bar).to.be.true;
      done();
    });
  });
```

An alternative would be to use [`findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) — which combines both actions (updating and retrieving) with one method call — instead, but that would require rewriting `Foo.statics.isBar`.

Comment: so many thx, I was getting crazy. I used the alternative, which makes the test more "readable" with less nesting. You made my day!

Comment: Just a silly question thus, why update() and findByIdAndUpdate() don't behave the same way?

Comment: @jndvdcn I think because of the extra work involved for `findByIdAndUpdate`, which under the hood will probably do an update-and-retrieve; if you just want to update a document in the database but don't need the updated version of the document directly, using `update` skips the unnecessary retrieve operation. Also, `update` can be used to update multiple documents, whilst `findByIdAndUpdate` targets only one document.